# How to get rid of lone `/` in URL of a citation in Bibliography without deleting it?

Tags: bibliographies, hyphenation, xurl

How do I group the lone `/` at the line above? or make it look prettier in any other way without deleting the said `/`? I've provided a MWE below. If it helps, I use latexmk with `-pdflua` which basically uses `lualatex` to make the my tex file and used `biber` for the bibliography database.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xurl}

\begin{filecontents*}{main.bib}
    @online{sandstorm_it_data_2020,
        title = {Data Hashing and Encryption and How They Enhance Security},
        url = {https://sandstormit.com/data-hashing-and-encryption-and-how-they-enhance-security/},
        author = {{Sandstorm IT}},
        urldate = {2021-09-17},
        date = {2020-05-11},
    }
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{main.bib}

\begin{document}

Yet another test~\parencite{sandstorm_it_data_2020}

\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Just a note: The fact that you use `lualatex` is relevant, as there is no lonely slash when using `pdflatex`. For some reason the spacing is different.

Comment: This seems to happen with lualatex + xurl. I don't know if it is intentional that xurl allows a break even there, since it allows breaks almost anywhere. If the very liberal line breaking of xurl isn't actually needed, then `\usepackage{url}` instead of xurl.

Comment: (Revision to my own comment: Or just remove the line about xurl.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be hard to break long URLs in text, and especially in bibliographies. The intention of the xurl package is to be *very* liberal about where to break a URL. I don't know if it's supposed to allow a break even at that point or not, or if what you are seeing is a bug.

But anyway, since you are using Biblatex you might find that just using the special provisions Biblatex has for handling breaking of URLs will be enough, and you don't need to use xurl.

In your example you get a good result if you just remove `\usepackage{xurl}`.

If you get problems breaking other URLs then you might want to use something like the following

```
% Permit linebreaks in urls at odd places if needed
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9000}
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{5000}
```

to allow breaking of URLs in more places, but only when it's needed. For details, see the Biblatex documentation!

Comment: Now I saw your previous question, so added a very similar answer to the original question instead.

Comment: Thanks! This solved the issue. Been bugging me for some time.